# which code set is easier to read/maintain?

Tags: android

Both of the codes below give me the same exact answers. I was just wondering which would be better programming practice for readability and maintainability. Would less lines of code be best? Would one affect the functionality of the program more than the other? any suggestions would be very much appreciated as I just want to learn the best practices for programming.
Here are the codes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < db.getAllDecks().size(); i++)
    {
        String CardCount = String.format("(%s)",db.getCardsForDeck(i+1).size());
        adapter2.add(db.getAllDecks().get(i).getDeck_name());
        adapter3.add(CardCount);
    }
```

or

```
for (Deck deck: deckList) {
        String deckName = deck.getDeck_name();
        adapter2.add(deckName);

        int count = db.getCardIds(deck).length;
        String strCount = Integer.toString(count);
        adapter3.add(strCount);
    }
```

Comment: These don't look equivalent to me.  Look how the construction of the card count string is different - one has parenthesis and the other does not.  Also the way the db is accessed is different in ways I can't see here.

Comment: The snippets are too short to give a clear answer.

Comment: In my opinion - second is easier to read and maintain. At least it is readable... I'm not sure I completely understand the first one..

Comment: Using an for-each iterator is always better than explicit for-loop, at least more generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall, I think the second code is clearer, and more readable.

It contains moe variable names that is able to tell what exactly it is used for, such as `deckName`, `count` and `strCount`. I can clearly see that you are getting every deck's name and card count and put them in different (list?) adapters.

For the first one, I apparently needed more time to comprehend what it is doing. So IMO, the second one!

Also if you could just rename `getDeck_name` to `getDeckName` that would be better for people to read. `getDeckName` follows the naming convention for naming Java methods i.e. camelCase.

Answer (score 0):

As per this book [Code Complete - Steve McConnell's](http://cc2e.com/)

> ***for loop*** is good choice when you need a loop that executes a specified number of times.
>   ***foreach loop*** is useful for performing an operation on each member of an array or the container.

for more visit : [Google books - Code Complete](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=LpVCAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA372&lpg=PA372&dq=Code+complete+Steve+McConnell+for+and+foreach+loop&source=bl&ots=GGMqiiBhKG&sig=-nq_WLuKRwCD-tS78jvofxYFg08&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1wIam1I_LAhWGbhQKHZUnC_gQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=Code%20complete%20Steve%20McConnell%20for%20and%20foreach%20loop&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get data from simple list thnn foreach loop is good to use but,,, if you want to data from exact position or to store from id than for-loop is better ..

and there is NO difference by performance wise both are same as well, as i know.
as my suggestion `use` **for loop** :)